# Simple exception handling for nested JAVA APIs

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, design-patterns, exception

I've a *pretty simple* "architectural" question this time.

Suppose that we have two APIs, one "external" and one "internal".
The implementation of the external, for each of his methods, calls, among the other things that it does, the corrispective method of the internal one (it's a 1 on 1 mapping of the methods, each remote method has a correspondent internal one).

*Additional information: The external interface is annotated with @Remote and the internal one (where is developed the business logic) is annotated with @Local.*

**FOR THE EXCEPTION HANDLING** my idea was to create 2 exceptions: one **internal** and one **external**.
Of course, the external one will wraps the internal, as the services do.

Speaking in code, the situation is like this:

```java
@Stateless
public class RemoteServiceBean implements RemoteService
{
     @Inject BusinessService businessSrv;
     public method1(external parameters) throws RemoteException
      {

          try 
          {      
                 bar();         
                 businessSrv.method1(internal parameters); 
          }
          //catch exceptions (also LocalException) and throws RemoteException
          catch(Exception1 | LocalException ...  e)
          { 
              Logging....
              throws RemoteException(e,e.getMsg());
          }
      }
}   

@Stateless
public class BusinessServiceBean implements BusinessService
{ 
      public method1(internal parameters) throws LocalException
      {
         try 
          {      
                 foo();         
          }
          //catch exceptions and throws LocalException
          catch(Exception1 | Exception2...  e)
          { 
              Logging....
              throws LocalException(e,e.getMsg());
          }
      }
}
```

**THE QUESTION IS:** Assuming that the services architecture must remain like this, in your opinion, is the exception handling correct? 
Are there some problems related to this exception's architecture?

All tips are welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: it's a very clean approach! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My ideas are highly subjective on the matter.

A design such as this makes me think that exceptions are being considered as a natural pheneomonen which should be caught regularly and dealt with.

Quoting directly from Joshua Bloch : exceptions are, as their name implies, to
be used only for exceptional conditions; they should never be used for ordinary
control flow

I for one would like to follow the conventions and try using the regular exceptions as much as possible. 
Excessive usage of exceptions and overcomplicated exception standarts generally drive developers away from using them in the first place. 
Of course I don't mean all business related exceptions could be wrapped in by a standart exception but I regularly see code pieces such as :

```
...
public void getEntityById(Long id)
{
    ...
    if(id == null)
    {
       throw new BusinessRelatedConventionCompliantException(
                1,4,TYPE.CORE_BUSINESS,"Entity id can not be null"); 
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

In my opinion it is much more logical to use the built-in exceptions most of the time :

```
...
public void getEntityById(Long id)
{
    ...
    if(id == null)
    {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Entity id param can not be null");  
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Illegal argument exception alone is overlooked many times, in my opinion.

Getting through the list of built in exceptions, I feel most of the time something explains what the problem is very clearly.

As for local and remote exceptions, I am a strong supporter of KISS principle when it comes to custom exception handling, I would never choose to seperate them.
My custom exceptions would already be used very rarely should I even choose to use it in the first place. I feel that the seperation adds very little 
value defining what the exceptional situation is and adds just a bit more boilerplate.

So wrapping it up, use standart built in exceptions as much as possible, catch exceptions only at recoverable flows not for controling&validations and 
keep it as simple as possible when it comes to exceptions.

Comment: It's also true that wrapping low level exception in higher ones is indicated in the book "effective java" as a best practice. Im a little bit confused right now. Another cons of the approach I've proposed is that runtime exception and checked exception are wrapped in the same superior except. In addition to this, leaving all the basic exception to be thrown will imply a huge load of catches client side. Heelp!

Answer (score 1):

one thing, when you say API, you should refer to an Interface. Your approach is very clean, hope that this services, both, implement the same interface.

Comment: Look at this new edit. Those are beans that implements different interfaces because the interfaces takes in imput different parameters.

Comment: if your services have 1 on 1 mapping of the methods then both should implement the same interface :)

Comment: But if the parameters in input are different? anyway this is OT.